# My Django image cant upload when i tried to update it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i am building a blog with django i successfully created a new post but when i tried to update the post everything updated but the image didnt update, it did not upload the image to the upload_to in the Posts model

here is my code

view.py

```
@login_required
def UpdatePost(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=pk)
    myForm = NewPostForm(instance = obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        myForm = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'danger',
            'message': "An Error Occured, pls try again later"
        }
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        category_id = request.POST.get('category')
        image = request.FILES.get('image') 
        if myForm.is_valid():
            if Posts.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(title=title, content=content, image=image, category_id=category_id, author_id=request.user.id):
                response_data = {
                    'SType': 'success',
                    'message': "Saved Successfully"
                } 
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
    context={ 
        'form':myForm,
        'title': obj.title,
        'category': Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/update.html', context)
```

update.html

```
<form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="PostNew__form"> {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Update a Blog Post</legend>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-0">
                {{ form.title | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
                {{ form.category | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>                
        </div>
        {{ form.content | as_crispy_field }}
        <div class="">
            {{ form.image | as_crispy_field }}
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h6 id="PostNew__show" ></h6>
        <img src=" {% static 'images/ajax-loader.gif' %}" style="Display:none;" id="PostNew__img">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info float-right" type="submit" id="PostNew__submit">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

model.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='blog_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'content', 'image']
```

pls how can i solve this problem, in the database, it stores the file name but its just the name, without the upload_to folder

Comment: If you're using a `ModelForm` why don't you just save the form instead of using `update()`? (also you generally shouldn't save `request.POST[field]` to your model, but `form.cleaned_data[field]`, because that's safe.)

Comment: also you're initialising your form wrong: use `instance=obj` not `instance=request.user.profile`

Comment: yes, i tried it but it didnt work

Comment: that's because you are passing the wrong instance to the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Django docs, it shows how to upload a file to a `Model` by creating the `Model` instance. The `update()` method on a queryset does not do the same, it shortcuts assignment of fields to just perform the database query. So it won't actually save the image file to storage.

You should assign the file field of the instance directly before saving, or you should just save the form. And you don't have to query the database because you already have the instance that you passed to the form. So either do this:

```
obj.image = image
obj.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
...
obj.save()
```

or, since you already have a ModelForm, you can just do this:

```
form.save()
```

Note however that your code instantiating the form is wrong:

```
form = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)  # not request.user.profile
```

If the form can't save directly because your model requires fields that are not part of the form, then you should use `commit=False`:

```
post = form.save(commit=False)
post.author = request.user  # and assign other fields that are not part of the form
post.save()
```